# Phonegap [cordova 3.2.0] The Google Play services resources were not found

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, google-play-services

I have added  `google-play-services.jar` into libs folder. Eclipse does not see any errors in project. However i am using `phonegap framework`, so build happens somehow with ant.
When i am compiling i am not getting any problems:

```
cordova build
Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
Preparing android project
Compiling app on platform "android" via command "cmd" /c C:\Users\kmoizik\Desktop\BTCproj\bbdebug\platforms\android\cordova\build
Platform "android" compiled successfully.
```

but in a runtime i got this error in `logcat`:
The Google Play services resources were not found Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included
Anybody can help ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in linking . You should link google play services as project library instead of throwing jar in the libs.

Answer (score 0):

don't worry about this v13 of `google play service` is buggy and will be fixed in next release take a look at screenshot i'm having same in my app[image: stacktrace]

Comment: thanks it is looking the same.  I thought i have troubles in ant configuration, or i am not addint right a library to the project